# How to transpose rows to columns during importing processes?

Tags: excel

I imported a simple text file using:

```
   Excel->from text->cancel
```

Then I found that I have 2 rows and 100 columns.
In fact, they should be 100 rows and two columns.Is there away to transpose the file during the importing process, as I do not want to import them and then transpose.

Comment: Run the macro recorder whilst you're doing the import and transpose manually. Once you have done that you'll have the code to change / amend to suit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, It is **not** possible to transpose the data with **any inbuilt way** while it is being imported.

You have to transpose the data after the data has been imported. Record a macro as @SkipIntro suggested in the comment above.

Having said that, there is a messy alternative. Import the data in an array and then write to the Excel file the way you want it. For this you will have to use VBA.

Here is am example.

Let's say that our text file looks like this

[image]

You can use this code to read the entire text file in an array in one go.

```
Dim MyData As String, strData() As String

Open "C:\Sample.Txt" For Binary As #1
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyData
Close #1
strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)
```

Now you can loop through the entire array `strData` and split the data and then finally write to the relevant section of the excel sheet